# Getting the max and min out of heightProperty() and widthProperty()

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

Is there any code, like `Math.max(num1, num2)` but for comparing two DoubleProperty s ?
I am currently trying to displaying a circle (that extends from Pane) that can automatically resize itself according to the size of the window. I would like to try getting the smaller value between the two for setting the radius of the circle.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DisplayCircle extends Application {
   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      Scene scene = new Scene(ResizableCircle(), 400, 300);
      primaryStage.setTitle("DisplayCircle");
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
   }

   public class ResizableCircle extends Pane {
      public ResizableCircle() {
         Circle c = new Circle(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
         c.centerXProperty().bind(widthProperty().subtract(10));
         c.centerYProperty().bind(heightProperty().subtract(10));


         // Need help setting the radius and binding it


         getChildren().add(c);
   }
}
```

Comment: What is your the current solution you wish to rewrite?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm this might help. Use bindings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Bindings.max(ObservableNumberValue op1, ObservableNumberValue op2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#max-javafx.beans.value.ObservableNumberValue-javafx.beans.value.ObservableNumberValue-) and [`Bindings.min(ObservableNumberValue op1, ObservableNumberValue op2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#min-javafx.beans.value.ObservableNumberValue-javafx.beans.value.ObservableNumberValue-) to bind an `ObservableNumberValue` to the minimum or maximum of two other observable values:

```java
DoubleProperty min = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
DoubleProperty max = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

min.bind(Bindings.min(widthProperty(), heightProperty()));
max.bind(Bindings.max(widthProperty(), heightProperty()));
```

Comment: Just to give more context and resources : This https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm might help!